# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no *** in java.library.path GraalVM

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to migrate an application to native, using graalVM. This app needs a dependance for crpyto purpose. It is currently using [this lib](https://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/products/core-crypto-toolkits/pkcs11-wrapper/). This app is a windows one.

This lib use a DLL (pkcs11wrapper.dll) included in the jar.
I am currently building the jar, then bulidong the native image using this command :

> native-image -cp target\single-proxy-native-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\dev\tools\m2\iaik\pkcs\pkcs11-wrapper\1.4\pkcs11-wrapper-1.4.jar  fr.devboxsante.cps.nativ.NativeCpsApplication -Djava.library.path=C:\dev\

(C:\dev\ contains the right dll)

It make the exe file, but when i try to execute it, it fails :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no pkcs11wrapper in java.library.path
> at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.NativeLibrarySupport.loadLibraryRelative(NativeLibrarySupport.java:132)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:197)
> at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
> at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1871)
> at fr.devboxsante.cps.nativ.NativeCpsApplication.main(NativeCpsApplication.java:15)

I have tryied a lot of things, putting the dll in the bin folder of the native jvm, adding it to the system32 folder, ...
You can find the project [here](https://github.com/aproust33/pkcs-native/tree/main)

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: try adding pkcs11-wrapper-1.4.jar in C:\dev\

Comment: It does not change anything :(

Comment: Please report your issue in this link https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues
Provide a reproducer to resolve it faster

Comment: Please try native-image tracing agent 
https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/Agent/